# Can a stochastic process be neither adapted to filtration nor previsible?

Tags: probability

The idea behind the question arises from my intuition about the concepts of 'adapted to filtration' and 'previsbility'.

If a process is **adapted**, it essentially means that the evolution of the universe upto time t reveals the history of our process **upto time t** also.

On the other hand, if a process is **previsible**, it means that the evolution of the universe upto time t reveals information about the process **beyond time t.**

If we are thinking in these terms, it becomes natural to ask if we can construct processes where the evolution of the universe upto time t reveals information about such processes only upto a time **prior to t, say t-1.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ be a probability space carrying a Brownian motion $(B_t)$ whose natural filtration I denote by $(\mathcal{F}_t)$. By definition, for every $t\geq0$, $B_t$ is $\mathcal{F}_t$-measurable, i.e. $(B_t)$ is adapted to $(\mathcal{F}_t)$.

As I understand, you wonder whether we may construct a process which is neither adapted nor previsible (aka predictable)? Consider the three processes

1. $X_t = B_t$,
2. $Y_t = B_{t-1}$ and
3. $Z_t = B_{t+1}$.

Then, $(X_t)$ is adapted to $(\mathcal{F}_t)$ by definition. So is $(Y_t)$ which is also known from the information contained in $\mathcal{F}_t$. Indeed, $(Y_t)$ is previsible as every $Y_t$ is $\mathcal{F}_{t-1}$-measurable. The process $(Z_t)$ however is neither adapted nor previsible. Knowledge about the evolution of the universe up to time $t$ merely reveals information about $Z_{t-1}$ yet you have no clue about the value of $Z_t$.

Comment: This is a very clear example! Thank your for writing this out. One quick question: do these processes have a particular name? If we have assigned a name to the other two classes - adapted and previsible - it seems we should also have a name for this class of processes.

Comment: Sorry but as far as I am aware these processes do not have an extra name. But I suppose not everything has a name: How do you call a stochastic process which is not a martingale? I dont believe we have an extra term for that. Neither am I aware of a name for a non-adapted process other than ``non-adapted''. Note that being previsible implies adapted. Things only get a name if they're just often. A non-adapted process is not used that often (in finance) as far as I know...

Comment: Yes, even I thought that non-adapted processes won't have a special name because they don't pop up that often in quantitative finance; just wanted to confirm from someone who knows more! Thanks a lot for your effort. :)